# Discord.js set bot role to highest

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions, discord, discord.js

I want my bot's role to be higher than any roles to mod people.
Is there any way to do that?
My Source Code:
[Repository](https://replit.com/@XXOctonal/bpcdiscordbot)

Comment: Your bot can only hoist roles 1 above it's highest role position. Therefore you will have to send a message explaining that the server owner must move the `bots` role to the top of the list.

Comment: Why can't I do it in the code way?

Comment: The "code way" doesn't exist.

Comment: OK, anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setPosition

Read the docs. As Tyler2P said, "Your bot can only hoist roles 1 above it's highest role position"

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setPosition).

```js
// Set the position of the role
role.setPosition(1)
  .then(updated => console.log(`Role position: ${updated.position}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```